# Reseting ng-option to default value from the Controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have the following select in my app:

```
<select ng-model="diagnose" ng-options="c as c.Name for c in diseases | orderBy:['Name']">
  <option value="">Diagnose*</option>
</select>
```

Once I send the data to the server, I reset the whole form, but the select goes to empty option instead of showing the empty value/hardcoded option.

I've tried with the following options:

```
$promisedb.then(function (data) {
  $scope.diagnose = [1];
});
```

And:

```
$promisedb.then(function (data) {
  $scope.diagnose = [0];
});
```

And:

```
$promisedb.then(function (data) {
  $scope.diagnose = '';
});
```

But so far no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: The default option! <option value="">Diagnose*</option>

Comment: did you try setting some value to the default option then resetting it to that value? say `<option value="default">Diagnose*</option>` then when you reset, you do `$scope.diagnose = 'default'`. does that work?

Comment: If I set a value `value="something"`, then it doesn't appear on the list. If I set `value=""` then it appears the first as default/placeholder, but it doesn't reset properly as stated above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could reset the `select` back to the default option using the `delete` command like so:

```
delete $scope.diagnose;
```

Demo:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.diseases = [
    'Disease 1',
    'Disease 2',
    'Other diseases...'
  ];
  $scope.reset = function () {
    delete $scope.diagnose;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="diagnose" ng-options="d for d in diseases">
      <option value="">Diagnose*</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</body>
```